# How to change the layout of the all products page?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, product-list

Can anyone tell me where I can change the layout of the all products page? I think this page is now having `3columns.phtml` layout but I need `2columns-left.phtml` layout.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**To change the product page layout:**

From the Admin menu, select Catalog > Manage Products.

Find the product in the list, and click to open the record.

In the Product Information panel on the left, select Design. Then in the Design section, set Page Layout to a different column configuration.

When complete, click the Save button.

**To change the category page layout:**

From the Admin menu, select Catalog > Manage Categories.

In the Categories tree, select the category level you want to change.

On the Custom Design tab, set Page Layout to “2 columns with right bar.”

Click the Save Category button.

Comment: dude you got my question in a wrong way your answer applicable for Individual product page but not that what I need.I need for the page see the image above anyway thanks for your time

Comment: that is category page so use the step for change layout of category page.

Comment: mannn your edit made my day thankyouu soo  muchh

Answer (score 28):

If you need to change every category page to `2column-left`, then use this layout update

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <catalog_category_layered>
      <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
          <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
        </action>
      </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
    <catalog_category_default>
      <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
          <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
        </action>
      </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

This is because as per layout, there are two types of categories `default` and `layered`. So magento uses two seperate layout handles in order to process them. Due to this in order to cover every categories you need to update these two layout handles.

But there is another awesome way to do this. Use this code inside your `local.xml` file.

```
<layout>
<catalog_category_view>
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
    </action>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

`catalog_category_view` is a unique layout handle that will process for every categories view in magento. However you cannot see any layout update using this layout handle in default magento. But the fact is, it does exist and it can be used for any layout update that should affect all categories.

Comment: no one option working for magento.1.9.2.4

Answer (score 9):

add the following code in your local.xml file

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
    </action>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: thankyou however the below answer worked anyway this process also may help me in future.